# Test class not covering parent record

Tags: apex

I am trying to cover below helper class but it's not covering. Below helper class updates Account Description whenever Contact desc is updated.

```
@isTest static void test1() {
 //Insert Account 
 Account acc = new Account( Name = 'Test Account', Website = 'www.test.com', Phone = '8888888888' ); 
 insert acc; 
  Contact c = new Contact( LastName = 'Test', Description = 'Test'); 
  insert c;

  Test.startTest(); 
  c.Description = 'Test123'; 
  update c; 
  Test.startTest();
}
```

Please use this code snippets.

Comment: Please upload your original trigger also.

Comment: Can you try first inserting account and then contact

Comment: Still not covered?

Comment: @isTest static void test1() {
        // Insert Account 
        Account acc = new Account(
           Name = 'Test Account',
           Website = 'www.test.com',
           Phone = '8888888888'
        );
        insert acc;
  
        Contact c = new Contact(
            LastName = 'Test',
            Description = 'Test';
        );
        insert c;
        
  Test.startTest();
  c.Description = 'Test123';
  update c;
  Test.startTest();

Please use this code snippets.

Comment: You are not calling that class. If this is helper class, please upload original trigger

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I got to know now that test classes cannot cover if trigger is inactive status. I got 100% coverage.

Comment: I would **highly** recommend **not** just writing test code for coverage.  You need to be using assert statements to check the actual functionality of the trigger.  Coverage really doesn't validate much besides that it doesn't crash.  Also, you have `test.startTest()` twice.  The second one should be `test.stopTest()`

Answer (score 1):

The above won't update the Account unless you write your code along the lines of the following:

```
@isTest static void test1() {
  //Insert Account 
  Account acc = new Account( Name = 'Test Account', Website = 'www.test.com', Phone = '8888888888' ); 
  insert acc; 

  Test.startTest(); 
  // Related Contact
  Account acctContact = new account( AccountId = accId, LastName = 'Test', account.Description = 'Test'); 
  upsert acctContact;
  Test.stopTest();

}
```

As you've written your test code, the Description is related to the contact and not to the Account. Neither is related to the Account.

If you want to insert the contact separately, you can do that, but you need to reference the `AccountId` of the Account. Your test code doesn't appear to do that. If you want to update the `Account.Description` from Contact, you'll need to reference `Account.Description` in your code.